# Html: link to specific section of my page

Tags: html, zend-framework, hyperlink

Zend app.I have a link in page1 pointing to specific section in page2:

```
<a href="mysite/index/index/#comments">link!</a>
```

my section "comments":

```
<div name="comments">here my comments</div>
```

This is not working.And the link is loading the page without targetting to the specified div.
Where Am I wrong?

thanks

Luca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [no `name` attribute for `div` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/attributes.html). Fragment identifiers are defined as referencing either [`a` elements via their `name`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.1) (old style, use it if you need to support Netscape 4) or [any element via its `id`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3) (modern style).

```
<div id="comments">here my comments</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
<div><a name="comments">here my comments</a></div>
```

or

```
<div id="comments">here my comments</div>
```

Comment: where is my code wrong?I mean why?=) your solution is working (I tried the 'id=comments' one)

Comment: Your code is not "wrong" in a moral sense. The guys at W3C just decided that div should not have a name attribute. There is a difference between id and name however. id attributes are searched before name attributes because you can have many name with the same value but only one id. Can I ask you why didn't you pick my answer?

Comment: Thanks! I asked where I was wrong.you found the solution (+1) but not the explaination..Quentin was faster